# Chat Socket.io + Express

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io

I need to create a chat with Socket.io Express and enabling conversations between two users per room, searching the web noticed several different ways to do there, be in no doubt that the most scalable and efficient way since the chat will have many users connected at the same time. Could anyone give me an idea or tip?

Comment: You need to ask a much more specific question.  This is far too broad for stack overflow.

Comment: How many is many? A simple server could do, or you might need a cluster  of servers with Redis  as the "binding" medium.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a starting point, you might be interested in this github project and start tweaking things.

https://github.com/socketio/socket.io/tree/master/examples/chat

I see, u also asked about scalability as well.  To be honest it is not possible to predict stuff like performance until u have the application up and running and has actually withness one.

If u ever got hit by one then u can always do profiling against the nodejs code and resolve the problem one by one. You can read more about how to do nodejs profiling **[here](https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/simple-profiling/)**.

Anyway, you might also want to check the project's licensing before using it thou.